# Custom view which inherits checkable from parent

Tags: android-layout, android, android-custom-view

I've a checkable `FrameLayout` as root in my `ListView`. It works very well with multi selection in `ListView`s.

However I'd like child views to inherit this state `duplicateParentState="true"`, **and** for some callback inside them once they get *checked/unchecked*.

Is there a way of doing this without having the checked `FrameLayout` loop through all child views and toggle them accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

For any future adventurers, I ended up solving it with this snippet inside `setChecked(boolean b)`

```
    // Check or Uncheck all child views that are checkable
    final int childCount = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View view = getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof Checkable) {
            ((Checkable) view).setChecked(mChecked);
        }
    }
```